# I am trying to do an email validator, and there is an error due to timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming

**I am trying to do an email validator to check if the email already exists and able to recieve emails or not**

## Code:

```
def verify_email(email):
    # Email address to verify
    addressToVerify = email

    # Get domain for DNS lookup
    splitAddress = addressToVerify.split('@')
    domain = str(splitAddress[1])
    print('Domain:', domain)

    try:
        # MX record lookup
        records = dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX')
        mxRecord = records[0].exchange
        mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
        print(f"No MX records found for {domain}")
        return False
    except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
        print(f"Domain {domain} not found")
        return False

    # SMTP lib setup
    server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=10)  # Set a timeout value in seconds (adjust as needed)

    # This is just a fake email that doesn't probably exist for smtp.mail(fromAddress)
    fromAddress = 'test@domain.com'

    # SMTP Conversation
    try:
        server.connect(mxRecord)
        server.helo(server.local_hostname)  # server.local_hostname(Get local server hostname)
        server.mail(fromAddress)
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
        server.quit()

        print("code:", code)
        print("message:", message)

        if code == 250:
            print('Yeah')
            return True
        else:
            print('Noooo')
            return False

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return False
```

## when i use the function it shows this error

```
An error occurred: timed out
```

I am trying to make an email validator to check if the email already exists or not

Comment: You can try increasing timeout to see if that resolves the issue. For example, set timeout=30 to allow a 30-second timeout.